# How to check what process is slowing down my RPi

Tags: memory

I have a PHP scraper that is running on my RPi. I noticed that since I have installed some additional software to the RPi the scraper takes 3/4 times longer to finish it's task than before. 
I wonder if there is any way to check what caused this drop in performances.

It doesn't really seem a problem with memory. While the script is up and running the output to `free -m` is

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           438        426         12          0         31        348
-/+ buffers/cache:         45        392
Swap:           99          0         99
```

That should indicate that I have more free memory (`392`) that I am actually using (`45`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/), which is an interactive process viewer for Linux.  From the [htop Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) (bold emphasis is my own):

> Htop is an interactive [system-monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor) process-viewer written for
> Linux. **It is designed to replace the Unix program [top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28Unix%29)**. It shows a
> frequently updated list of the processes running on a computer,
> normally ordered by the amount of CPU usage. Unlike top, htop provides
> a full list of processes running, instead of the top
> resource-consuming processes. Htop uses color and gives visual
> information about [processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit), [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_space) and [memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access_memory) status.
>
> Users often deploy htop in cases where Unix top does not provide enough
> information about the systems processes, for example when trying to
> find minor [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) in applications. Compared to top, it provides
> a more convenient, cursor-controlled interface for killing processes.

This is what I use, and I think it works really well.

Comment: With `htop` I noticed that the problem is not really memory but processor use. The php script reaches 100% of CPU for every cycle of the crawler. Is it a problem? Or simply does it mean there's no other process running then the crawler takes the whole pie?

Comment: That's when you look at the load averages for the Pi. If the load average is above 1 when the CPU is at 100% then it's slowing everything down. If the  load average is below 1 but the CPU usage is at 100%, then it won't slow anything down.

Answer (score 2):

Using `top` you can sort by cpu or memory usage.
Once you run `top`, hit `shift-F` to choose how to sort the output.
`k` sorts by cpu
`n` sorts by memory usage

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command "top" for see what´s going on each process.